# Oracle SQL Developer - Records per page in a grid

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have used Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer in the past and am now being asked to use Oracle SQL Developer at work. In PL/SQL Developer the program restricted the records per page that would be retrieved and I could go into Edit -> Preferences and select SQL Window to ensure all records were retrieved:

[PL/SQL user preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utjx5.png)

Can someone let me know if there is a users preference where I can ensure all records are captured in Oracle SQL Developer 18.1?

Comment: What does number of rows returned have to do with beautifying?

Comment: Also are you talking about the 'Query Result' window where results are shown in a grid with fetch (page, sort of) sizes that are recommended to be between 50 and 200 rows ([see here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/05/oracle-sql-developer-fetching-sql-statement-result-sets/)), or the Script Output window ([see here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/01/scripts-on-spooling-and-output-to-screen-in-oracle-sql-developer/))?

Comment: ctrl+end will do a full fetch in the grid, just be careful what you ask for

Answer (score 6):

In Oracle SQL Developer you can (eventually) get all rows. Still, it will fetch results N rows at a time. If you keep scrolling down in the Query Results tab, it will keep on fetching results.

[image]

How many rows at a time? It is given by this parameter `Sql ArrayFetch Size`, and it is limited to something between 50 and 200.

[image: SQL developer config options]

If you still want to get ALL of them results at once with no intervention from editor, run the script (usually F5) instead of using the option to run the statement. The result will show up similar to being presented in SQL*plus, terminal-like, in the Script Output tab.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer, which I am upvoting now, but also, the premise of the question is a bit iffy...if I'm querying a table and have a BILLION row result set, under no circumstances should any tool really try to print all of those rows in a screen..at best they should be spooled to a file.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith indeed. But also, I'm not the one to tell people what they should not do. This is how tool works, OP is free to try out and find out how to do things that suit them better. :)